# Access is denied for SQLDumper.exe in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqldump

I want to run SQLDumper.exe with process ID 6392 which is the ID of my Express edition. While running I get this error from the OS

> access is denied

[image]

I've given full control to the SQL Express account name but still get the error. What access should I grant in order to make it work properly?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running CMD using administrative Privileges.

Start->CMD->right Click on it and click run as administrator

[image]